# Should I be able to hear the DTMF codes Twilio plays?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am setting up an auto-answer in Twilio that plays the DTMF code "9".

When I call the number, it answers correctly, but in testing, I cannot audibly hear that it is playing a DTMF tone.

I can hear other commands like `twiml.say('hello')`.

I have validated that the more `w` chars I add, the longer the line stays open.

> Q: Is that how DTMF codes are supposed to work, or they should be audible?

Example code:

```js
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  twiml.say('Hello!');

  // Dial "9" three times, with pauses between each
  twiml.play({ digits: 'w9w9w9' });

  return callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When Twilio plays DTMF tones, it does so [out-of-band](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-dtmf#in-band-vs-out-of-band-signaling), so you will not be able to hear them yourself on the audio line.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I wish I'd noticed that in the docs for the `play` API. I spent at least an hour trying different ways of specifying digits before guessing maybe these tones aren't audible. Probably this is obvious to anyone who knows phone line stuff... but I don't :)

Comment: Is that new, in the last couple of years?  I definitely used to hear the tones.

Comment: ... actually, it's much more awkward.  When I have Twilio call my Google Voice number and I answer the call through the GVoice web interface I hear the tones (3212333w222w399w3212333w322321: "Mary Had A Little Lamb"; in-band) but when I answer the call through GVoice on my phone I hear no tones, just faint clicks and pauses that take up the same amount of time (out-of-band I guess). Awkward.